# How to check whether a String fully matches a Regex in Scala?

Tags: regex, scala

Assume I have a Regex pattern I want to match many Strings to.

```
val Digit = """\d""".r
```

I just want to check whether a given String fully matches the Regex. What is a good and idiomatic way to do this in Scala?

I know that I can pattern match on Regexes, but this is syntactically not very pleasing in this case, because I have no groups to extract:

```
scala> "5" match { case Digit() => true case _ => false }
res4: Boolean = true
```

Or I could fall back to the underlying Java pattern:

```
scala> Digit.pattern.matcher("5").matches
res6: Boolean = true
```

which is not elegant, either.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: I think `"5" match { case Digit() => true case _ => false }` looks better than using underlying pattern object.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Answering my own question I'll use the "pimp my library pattern"

```
object RegexUtils {
  implicit class RichRegex(val underlying: Regex) extends AnyVal {
    def matches(s: String) = underlying.pattern.matcher(s).matches
  }
}
```

and use it like this

```
import RegexUtils._
val Digit = """\d""".r
if (Digit matches "5") println("match")
else println("no match")
```

unless someone comes up with a better (standard) solution.

**Notes**

- I didn't pimp `String` to limit the scope of potential side effects.
- `unapplySeq` does not read very well in that context.

Comment: Did you have any particular side effect in mind? I pimped `String` instead, and this works fine so far, in spite of `String`'s member function  `matches(regex: String)`.

Comment: I pimped with a function `misses` too. Match and missmatch :-)  It's so annoying to have to write `!s.matches(r)` instead of `s misses r`. Hmm

Comment: How about the built-in `"5" matches "\\d"` which @polygenelubricants suggested?

Comment: Data matches a pattern, not vice-versa. The scaladoc on Regex makes a big deal about the lack of a boolean for "matches".  Personally, I think you've swapped a nice match for a clunkier if-else. If you don't care about groups, use `case r(_*) =>`.

Comment: There has to be a way to do this without importing an external library...

Comment: @JameelaHuq Folks visiting this question will be pleased with 2.13, where Regex finally gets matches. https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6521

Answer (score 61):

I don't know Scala all that well, but it looks like you can just do:

```
"5".matches("\\d")
```

#### References

- http://langref.org/scala/pattern-matching/matching

Comment: Well, that works, but has the disadvantage that the pattern is compiled on every try to match. I'd like to avoid that for performance reasons.

Comment: @mkneissl: then it looks like your `.pattern.matcher(text).matches` is the way to go. You can hide the verbosity under some utility method or overloaded operator or something if Scala supports it.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I am going to do, see my answer. I hope answering one's own questions is accepted behaviour on Stack Overflow... Meta says it is...

Comment: @ed. that's even slower and cruftier, so why?

Comment: The link given as a reference is broken

Answer (score 15):

For the full match you may use [**unapplySeq**](http://scala-tools.org/scaladocs/scala-library/2.7.1/scala/util/matching/Regex.html#unapplySeq). This method tries to match target (whole match) and returns the matches.

```
scala> val Digit = """\d""".r
Digit: scala.util.matching.Regex = \d

scala> Digit unapplySeq "1"
res9: Option[List[String]] = Some(List())

scala> Digit unapplySeq "123"
res10: Option[List[String]] = None

scala> Digit unapplySeq "string"
res11: Option[List[String]] = None
```

Comment: While true, the primary use of unapply and unapplySeq is implicitly in the `case`s of a `match` block.

Answer (score 12):

```
  """\d""".r.unapplySeq("5").isDefined            //> res1: Boolean = true
  """\d""".r.unapplySeq("a").isDefined            //> res2: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Hmm. Why posting a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/3022478/158823 two years later?

Comment: Your original question asked for a result ending in 'true' or 'false', not 'Some' or 'None'. As far as I'm aware isDefined was not part of the library 2 years ago, but maybe it was. Anyway, my answer is not a duplicate ;-)

Comment: I see, it isn't a duplicate. Sorry.

Comment: No probs ;-) My mistake, I should have explained why I'm using isDefined in my answer. Just giving code as an answer is generally a bad idea, so it's my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Using Standard Scala library and a pre-compiled regex pattern and pattern matching (which is scala state of the art):

```
val digit = """(\d)""".r

"2" match {
  case digit( a) => println(a + " is Digit")
  case _ => println("it is something else")
}
```

more to read: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/util/matching/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the regex:

```
val Digit = """^\d$""".r
```

Then use the one of the existing methods.

Comment: I don't think anchors is the issue here. `String/Pattern/Matcher.matches`, in Java at least, is whole string match already. I think the issue is just style/idiom for regex-ing in Scala, i.e. what those "one of the existing methods" are.

Comment: @polygenelubricants Well, `Matcher.matches` is an aberration. Ok, it makes some optimizations possible, though I don't know if the Java library actually takes advantage of it. But the _standard_ way for Regular Expressions to express that a full match is required is to use anchors. Since the Scala library does _not_ provide a full match method, then the proper way to do it is to use anchors. Either that, or use the Java library.

Comment: Anchoring is not the problem. See also the "123" example in Vasil's answer.

Comment: @mkneissl In what way is `findFirstIn` with `"""^\d$""".r` different from using `unapplySeq` with `"""\d""".r`?

Comment: @Daniel You might be missing the point -- My question was, if I only need to know if a regex matches fully, what is a good way to express that in Scala. There are a lot of working solutions, but in summary I think there is a method missing in Regex that just does that and nothing else.
To answer the question in your commment: The difference from unapplySeq to findFirstMatch is, that I have to change the Regex to add the anchors. Both methods neither immediately express my intent nor return a boolean value, that is I'd have to go from Option to Boolean (no problem, but adding more clutter).

Comment: @mkneissl I dislike the concept of Java's `matches`, but ok. As for `Option` vs `Boolean`, add `nonEmpty` to the end and you'll get the `Boolean`.