# What is the idiomatic scala way of finding, if a given string contains a given substring?

Tags: regex, string, scala, substring, contains

I have two strings in scala and I want to find out, if the bigger string (`needle`) contains a smaller string (`haystack`).

What I found is doing it with regexps and matches like this ([from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021813/how-to-check-whether-a-string-fully-matches-a-regex-in-scala)):

`needle.r.pattern.matcher(haystack).matches`

which is (1) grossly overcomplicated for such a simple problem, but more importantly, (2) doesn't work for me, because

`"needle".r.pattern.matcher("Finding needle in haystack").matches`

returns

`Boolean = false`

Comment: I'm maybe missing something, but What's wrong with contains ?

Comment: I was just about to ask the same thing

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, I just haven't found it :) that's all.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

If you want to do it with maximum efficiency, you may have to write it yourself (or find a good substring searching algorithm somewhere).  If you just want it to work at all, then in Scala:

```
scala> "Finding needle in haystack" contains "needle"
res0: Boolean = true

scala> "Finding needle in haystack" indexOf "needle"
res1: Int = 8
```

These are *not* regex searches.  You aren't using the regex match correctly either (edit: because that code asks for an exact match to the whole string, not to find a matching substring), but that's a different issue.  If you want a count of the number of matches, you can do something like

```
scala> "needle".r.findAllIn("Finding needle in haystack").length
res2: Int = 1
```

Comment: If anyone's wondering, `contains` and `indexOf` are just methods on `java.lang.String` and there is no Scala magic going on here. I haven't looked at the source but I expect they're well-optimized methods.

Comment: And what's so slow or unoptimized about them?

Answer (score 19):

Although answered I thought I would also offer this regex style

```
scala> "I have a needle in my haystack" matches ".*needle.*"
res10: Boolean = true
```

Comment: This is slow, and only works if there are no line terminators.

Comment: Compared to the other answer.  indexOf() (which contains() uses) is well-optimized both at Java level and within the JVM.

Comment: @EdStaub it's not the subject of the question, but this answer is still relevant if regex is necessary. indexOf and contains don't seem to work with regex.